# Как сделать разницу в днях без учёта таймзон в DayJs

Tags: javascript, datetime, dayjs

у меня дата дата приходит в формате `"2023-11-29T02:00:00+03:00"`
Мне необходимо получить разницу в днях от текущей даты, без учёта времени, таймзон.
допустим, сегодня `28 ноября` и у меня лондонская таймзона. Но разница между завтрашним и сегодня - всегда 0 дней.

```
 const date1 = dayjs("2023-11-29T02:00:00+03:00");
 const date2 = dayjs(dayjs()); // смотрю, например, 28 ноября в лондонской таймзоне
 console.log(date1.diff(date2, 'd')); // получим 0
```

Я пробовал делать .startOf('D') для всех дат - не помогло.
Я пробовал делать .tz('Europe/Moscow') - не помогло.

Почему все время 0 и как получить 1 день разницы дат?
Все даты в объекте в итоге становятся
$d: Tue Nov 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Среднее время по Гринвичу)

Answer (score 1):

метод `diff` у date.js считает через миллисекунды, а потом делит на 60/60/24 и округляет в меньшую сторону с погрешностью (читай неправильно), т.е. возвращает количество полных *суток*, а не дней. Можно использовать такой костыль:

```js
const date1 = dayjs("2023-11-29T02:00:00+03:00").hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(1);
const date2 = dayjs().hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(1);
console.log(date1.diff(date2, "day", true)); //последнее true будет возвращать неокругленное значение, по нему видно, откуда проблема.
```

Вы можете обрезать время с поясом, типа `strDate.split("T")[0]` тогда обе даты будут в поясе браузера, но все равно, значение будет 0,9999999... если не обнулить даты до миллисекунд как в примере выше.